# Pass parameters to @select of multiselect in Vue.js - vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-multiselect

I am trying to pass parameter to **@select** event function in ***Vue.js***

***HTML***

```
 <template>
    <div class="container">

<div v-for="(billItem, k) in billItems" :key="k" >
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for=""> Products</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Product</label>
            <multiselect 
                v-model="billItem.billItem_selectedGood" 
                :options="productOptions" 
                :close-on-select="true" 
                :clear-on-select="false" 
                :hide-selected="true" 
                :preserve-search="true" 
                placeholder="Select Product" 
                label="name" 
                track-by="name" 
                :preselect-first="false"
                id="example"
                @select="onSelect_selectedGood"
            >
            </multiselect>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</template>
```

***JS***

```
<script>

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      form: new Form({
      })
    }
  },
  methods : {
    onSelect_selectedGood( option, id) {
      console.log("onSelect_selectedGood");
      console.log(option);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      
  }
}
</script>
```

**My Question:** How can I pass **billItem** to **onSelect_selectedGood** so I can access it inside the function.

Something like
`@select="onSelect_selectedGood(billItem)"` then implement the function like this `onSelect_selectedGood( billItem, option, id)`

Let me know how I can achieve it.

Comment: What library are you using here?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy am using this library vue-multiselect ( https://vue-multiselect.js.org )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it simply like :

```
 @select="onSelect_selectedGood($event,billItem)"
```

and in your methods :

```
 methods : {
   onSelect_selectedGood( selectedOption,billItem) {
      console.log(  selectedOption,billItem);

   },
}
```

the passed parameters are the `$event` which is the `selectedOption` and `billItem`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access all `billItem, option` and `id`, you can create a custom input component:

**CustomInput.vue**

```
<template>
  <multiselect 
      v-model="billItem.billItem_selectedGood" 
      :options="productOptions" 
      :close-on-select="true" 
      :clear-on-select="false" 
      :hide-selected="true" 
      :preserve-search="true" 
      placeholder="Select Product" 
      label="name" 
      track-by="name" 
      :preselect-first="false"
      id="example"
      @select="onSelect_selectedGood"
   >
</multiselect>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['billItem'],
  methods: {
    onSelect_selectedGood( option, id) {
      console.log("onSelect_selectedGood");
      console.log(option);
      console.log(this.billItem)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and then using it in your html:

```
<custom-input 
  :billItem="billItem"
/>
```

Because you passed `billItem` as a prop, you can access it by `this.billItem` in custom component.

Comment: thanks for the help.  am getting this error [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <custom-input> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: You need to register custom component https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html. But @Boussadjra Brahim solution is simpler.